# Excel formula if returns false

Tags: excel, formula

I have the following formula:

`=IF(I2=0;IF(D2="*CONTADO*";K2=I2;K2=7);K2=I2)`

For some reason it returns FALSE, where it should copy the value of I2 or else make it 7.
Aside of that, I don't know if the right way to make a "contains" is just asterisk inside the quotes.

**EDIT:**

formula now reads as:

```
=IF(I2=0;IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ALBARAN";D2));ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CONTADO";D2)));I2;7);I2)
```

It returns false when it matches the searched words in the cells.

I did a small test with

```
=ESNUMERO(BUSCAR("CLAVIJA";D3))
```

*(to clarify it, Spanish Excel translates every formula name (sigh). ESNUMERO is ISNUMBER and BUSCAR is SEARCH. I've been translating it the whole time for your understanding.)*

and did an auditory of the formula. It gets a #N/A when finding "CLAVIJA" even in the cell reads just like that. The value of D3 is "CLAVIJA MULTIPLE 10-16A T.T.LA".

Comment: `K2=I2` and `K2=7` will evaluate to TRUE or FALSE. Drop the `K2=` portion. As far as the 2nd question, you can use `ISNUMBER` and `SEARCH`.

Comment: so how can I make k2 have the value of I2 or 7?

Comment: Put the formula into cell K2

Comment: I feel kind of dumb. Thank you guys.

Comment: It seems isnumber+search is not working. 
=IF(I2=0;IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(OR("ALBARÁN";"CONTADO");D2));I2;7);I2)
it doesn't apply, as if it was finding nothing. I tried a simple isnumber(search in another cell with a clear value and it returns false (meaning not finding the word)

Comment: Your usage is incorrect for SEARCH. It should be like `=IF(I2=0;IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ALBARAN";D2;1));ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CONTADO";D2;1)));I2;7);I2)`.

Comment: however, @shrivallabha.redij, I created a simpler version of the formula for testing purposes, 
```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CLAVIJA";D3));"YES";"NO")
```

and it returns false, despite the cell contains "CLAVIJA"

Comment: Stay on the formula cell and go to `Formula >> Formula Auditing >> Evaluate Formula` and step through formula evaluation to check where it is failing...

Comment: I did, thanks for the clue @shrivallabha.redij, It returns false on SEARCH("CONTADO". Isn't it looking for a substring? Or is it a full string comparison?

Comment: Yes it looks for substring only and your formula works for me. I am stumped by this strange behavior.

Comment: When I do the same in the test example I have, being =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CLAVIJA";D3)), and audition it, it gives a #N/A, but the word clavija is indeed in D3.

Comment: @Germán Edit your question and copy/paste your exact test example (as text), and a copy/paste of your exact formula.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld done.

Comment: You have a typo here `IF(O(` which should be `IF(OR(`.

Comment: corrected it, as I put in edit, I'm translating it from Spanish, which is O.

Comment: @Germán I think you are using the wrong function.  According to the Microsoft Translator, in Spanish you should use:  `=ESNUMERO(HALLAR("CLAVIJA";D3))`.  `BUSCAR` translates as `LOOKUP`

Answer (score 1):

Here in image you can see, you can achieve your desired results, I have done with 3 test cases
FORMULA TO DO `=IF(I2=0,IF9D2="CONDTADO",12,7),I2)`

```
B2 0   D2 *CANTADO*  I2 0  K2 0   L2    OUTER AND INNER IFS ARE TRUE
B3 3   D3 *CANTADO*  I3 3  K3 3   L3 0  OUTER IF IS FALSE 
b4 7   D4 *CANTAD*   I4 0  K4 7   L4 0  OUTER IF IS TRUE BUT INNER IS FALSE
```

Comment: Please - answers should not be images, but text, possibly with supporting images. Also - we now have an issue with ISNUMBER and SEARCH, which is not what you have in your image.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing SEARCH by FIND.

Comment: `FIND` (`ENCONTRAR` in Spanish) will be case-sensitive.  `SEARCH` (`HALLAR` in Spanish) will be case-insensitive.